# How to prevent room-switching if you assign a room type to a customer in a Hotel booking database?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

It would be much easier to assign a room number to a guest at the time of reservation but this can lose business.

The alternative is to instead assign a room-type to a guest at the time of reservation and have an inventory of how many rooms of each time the hotel has.

A problem, however, is ensuring each customer will be able to stay in the same room for all their stay. Suppose there are $n$ Deluxe Rooms $D_1, \ldots, D_n$ in a hotel. How to prevent a situation where each room $D_i$ could be fully-booked except on day $i$. Then according to the database there is availability for a Deluxe room each day but if another customer would to book this room type then at check-in they’d find out they would have to change room every night of their stay.
How can you prevent such a circumstance of overbooking without assigning exact room numbers to guests at time of reservation?

Answer (score 0):

Your data consists of an inventory of room types, booked rooms, and occupied rooms.

The `Room` data structure consists of a room number, room type, and maximum number of guests.

The `Inventory` data structure consists of a list of `Room` instances.

The `BookedRoom` data structure consists of the reservation maker, the number of guests, the quoted rate per night, a start date, and an end date.

The `Booked` data structure consists of a list of `BookedRoom` instances.

The `OccupiedRoom` data structure consists of the reservation maker, a room number, the number of guests, the actual rate per night, a start date, and an end date.

The `Occupied` data structure consists of a list of `OccupiedRoom` instances.

When a person makes a reservation, you check the `Booked` and `Inventory` to see if a room of the room type requested is available.  Your system can suggest an alternate if the room type is unavailable.  Yes, this query will take a few seconds, but the customer isn't going to notice because the reservation taker is getting additional information.

When a person checks in, you check the `Booked`, `Occupied`, and `Inventory` to make sure the room is available.  Your system can suggest an alternate if the room type is unavailable.  Yes, this query will take a few seconds,